# How to access dynamic key values in nested objects

Tags: javascript, object

This is my JSON file:

```
{
 "Key": "some-key",
        "some-key": {
        "comLength": 1
        },
}
```

How do I access the `comLength` value?

Comment: "some-key" is duplicate. Do you mean "some_other_key"?

Comment: both keys are same

Comment: You mean `value[value.Key].comLength`?

Comment: When asking a question it's very important to show us your attempt to solve the problem. Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to write the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this

1. parse to custom object
2. do a For-loop by the required property
3. break the loop as soon I found the match

Comment: No reason to iterate

Answer (score 0):

Considering your object variable is named `someObject`, you can access it like:

```
var comLength = someObject["some-key"].comLength
```

**Example**:

```js
var someObject = {
     "Key": "some-key",
     "some-key": {
        "comLength": 1
     },
}

var comLength = someObject["some-key"].comLength;

console.log(comLength);
```

Comment: The problem is that I do not know the name of the key

Comment: If you don't know the key, how will you know which property to access from object?

Answer (score 0):

You can reference it via the dot notation (.) and the square notation ([]) (the [] notation is mandatory in case of the property key of `some-key` because of the `-`)

```js
const obj = {
    "Key": "some-key",
    "some-key": {
            "comLength": 1
        }
};


console.log(obj["some-key"].comLength);
console.log(obj["some-key"]["comLength"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont know the key but know the property you want inside the key then looping might help

```
var my_obj = {
  Key: "some-key",
  "some-key": {
    comLength: 1,
  },
};

// the name of the property you want
property = "comLength";

for (item in my_obj) {
  // checks if the the property exists
  if(my_obj[item].hasOwnProperty(property)){ 
    console.log(my_obj[item][property]);
  }
}
```

Gives output

```
1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const json = {
  "Key": "some-key",
  "some-key": {
    "comLength": 1
  },
}

var key1 = 'some-key';
var key2 = 'comLength';

const value = json[key1][key2];
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 